# VS Code - How do I select Jupyter Kernel for a workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have some `.ipynb` files in a VS Code workspace (they're all in the same directory).

This is my workspace config at `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python"
}
```

I know how to set the default python interpreter for the workspace, but couldn't figure out a way to do the same for the jupyter kernel, and every time I open a notebook file, VS Code would prompt me to select a kernel for the notebook opened.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913063/vscode-jupyter-nb-default-python-kernel

Comment: I've looked through this documentation]: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference for such a setting and have not found one

Comment: I'm looking for the same configuration... if you discover something, please tell me! Thanks!

Comment: Submitted as an issue to the VSC team and upvote if you'd like to see the feature added: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130946

Comment: "python.pythonPath" is deprecate. Now the command is: "python.defaultInterpreterPath"