# Automatically picking notebook kernel : Vs Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want a way to automatically select a specific kernel automatically each time I create a `.ipynb` file in VS code, searched and all I found are methods to fix other issues (like when you close and reopen Vs code the kernel of an already existing notebook isn't selected).

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `python.defaultInterpreterPath` not do that?

Comment: it shows the kernel as default but it doesn't pick it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement itself, this is [an existing feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130946) on github.

Usually, `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in `settings.json` can achieve the same goal.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516550/vs-code-how-do-i-select-jupyter-kernel-for-a-workspace, which is mentioned in the issue ticket? Actually, there's a deleted answer over there which essentially says this.